# Why won't my python code work for calculating wages?

Tags: python

I'm a beginner and am trying to write an application which can calculate wages based on normal hours and shift work. I am not sure why my code isn't working.

```
hourly_rate= float(input("Enter hourly rate: "))
normal_hours= float(input("Enter hours worked: "))
shift_hours= float(input("Enter amount of shift hours: "))

Total_gross =
    if shift_hours >= 1:
    return (hourly_rate * normal_hours) + (0.125 * hourly_rate * (shift_hours)).

  else:
  return hourly_rate * normal_hours  # Otherwise Normal Payment
    return hourly_wage *normal_hours.



print(f"Total_gross: {pay:.2f} ")
```

Comment: How is it not working?

Comment: How can you have a "=" and then a newline, which consist of "if" and "else"?

Answer (score 2):

I was not able to fully understand what exactly you were intending to do. However, does this work for you?

````
hourly_rate= float(input("Enter hourly rate: "))
normal_hours= float(input("Enter hours worked: "))
shift_hours= float(input("Enter amount of shift hours: "))

if shift_hours >= 1:
    Total_gross = (hourly_rate * normal_hours) + (0.125 * hourly_rate * (shift_hours))

else:
  Total_gross= hourly_rate * normal_hours  # Otherwise Normal Payment
    #return hourly_wage *normal_hours.



print(f"Total_gross: {Total_gross:.2f} ") ```
````